# root.iconbitmap() forces tkinter to enter a temporary eventloop?

Tags: python, tkinter, event-loop

Does `wm_iconbitmap` method forces tkinter to enter an event loop while it processes the icon file? Is there a way to avoid this? Check this example that illustrates this:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap('images/logo.ico') # Without `mainloop()` shows the window, means the events have started being processed?
time.sleep(3)
```

I couldn't find any related info in the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.html#M31) either.
Thanks in advance :)

Edit: A little more research shows that `root.iconbitmap()` does not enter event loop, maybe because there is no icon to process/check? But that would not answer why `root.iconphoto` does not enter an event-loop when called

Comment: When I run your code with a valid path to an `ico` file, I get a `_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "/path/to/icon.ico" not defined. How are you not getting any errors with your `ico` file?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Prolly because you are not on windows? Linux uses xbm IIRC, and IDT macOS has one.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin From your bio: "_I'm a Linux fan, and do all my computer stuff on an Ubuntu._" I suppose you are on a linux distro, try xbm files then

Comment: I'm glad you're finding my user profile handy; after all, that's why I wrote it :-). I tried using an `xbm` image (and yes, the path is valid), but I still get the same error message. I feel like I heard that `iconbitmap()` only works on Windows, is that true?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Hehe. I'm not sure about that but maybe that is the case, might need `iconphoto`  but it does not force an event loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventloop and the created window are different things. In your case it is the window that is forced into existence and is mentioned in the source code as a side effect:

> Side effects:
>
> One or all windows may have their icon changed.
> The Tcl result may be modified. The window-manager will be
> initialised if it wasn't already. The given window will be forced
> into existence.

See the [source code](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/win/tkWinWm.c#L716) for details.